# How many different possibilities are there?

Tags: combinatorics

I was doing this cool real life puzzle game in Shanghai, China. It works like this:

> You and a group of friends are locked in a room together - no smartphones, no cameras - and your task is to get out. One of the questions was a number puzzle to unlock a digital keypad.
>
> Here is what it said:
>
> The code contains only these numbers (but must use them all) $4, 6, 9$
>
> It is a $6$ digit code.
>
> The code ends in $4$.
>
> $4$ and $9$ are never consecutive.

The correct answer was $4,6,6,9,6,4$.

I feel I just got lucky at getting the code correct. So my question is this:

> How many different possibilities are there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I got two different answer (one of 38 and another of 137) I decided to write a program to figure out the answer through guess and check. I got the answer of 38.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

## The code contains only these numbers (but must use them all) 4,6,9
## It is a 6 digit code.
## The code ends in 4.
## 4 and 9 are never consecutive.

$n = 10000;
$total = 0;
until ($n eq 99999)
{
 $n++;

    # make sure it only contains 4,6,9
    next if ($n =~ m/0|1|2|3|5|7|8/);

    # make sure it countians 6 & 9 (4 is already included)
    next if ($n !~ m/6/);
 next if ($n !~ m/9/);

    # make sure 4 & 9 are never consecutive
    next if ($n =~ m/49/);
 next if ($n =~ m/94/);

    # make sure 9 & 4 are never consecutive (Because we arent looking at the 4)
    next if ($n =~ m/9$/);

    print $n . "4\n";
 $total++;

}

print "\n\nTotal: $total\n";
```

OUTPUT

```
446964
466964
469644
469664
469964
646964
666964
669644
669664
669964
696444
696464
696644
696664
696964
699644
699664
699964
964444
964464
964644
964664
966444
966464
966644
966664
966964
969644
969664
969964
996444
996464
996644
996664
996964
999644
999664
999964
```

Total: 38

Comment: I think there are some possibilities missing in this list, all of which end in 64.  For example, 999964 and 966664 don't appear here.  (I think there are an additional 15 of this type.)

Comment: You are correct. Now there is 38!

446964
466964
469644
469664
469964
646964
666964
669644
669664
669964
696444
696464
696644
696664
696964
699644
699664
699964
964444
964464
964644
964664
966444
966464
966644
966664
966964
969644
969664
969964
996444
996464
996644
996664
996964
999644
999664
999964


Total: 38

Comment: Thanks - I'm glad this checked out.

Answer (score 2):

Let $N_{a,b}$ be the codes of length $a$ that end in $b$ and have no adjacent $4$'s and $9$'s.  Each code of length $a$ that ends with $b$ can be extended uniquely to a code of length $a+1$ that ends in $c$, unless $(b,c)=(4,9)$ or $(9,4)$.  So
$$
N_{a+1,4}=N_{a,4}+N_{a,6} \\
N_{a+1,6}=N_{a,4}+N_{a,6}+N_{a,9} \\
N_{a+1,9}=N_{a,6}+N_{a,9},
$$
or
$$
N_{a+1}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 0\\1 & 1 & 1\\0 & 1 & 1\end{array}\right)\cdot N_{a}
$$
in a matrix notation, where $N_{0}=(1,1,1)^{t}$.  One finds that $N_6=(169,239,169)^t$, so there are $169$ six-number codes ending with a $4$.  We need to subtract the codes of this type that don't use all three numbers… since $4$'s and $9$'s can't be adjacent, these are just those codes containing $4$'s and $6$'s only, of which there are $2^5=32$ ending in $4$.  The result is $169-32=137$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n$, $b_n$, and $c_n$ be the number of n-digit codes that end in a 4, 9, or 6, respectively, without the requirement that all 3 digits are used.

If $e_n$ gives the total number of n-digit codes, then

$a_n=e_{n-1}-b_{n-1}$, $b_n=e_{n-1}-a_{n-1}$, and $c_n=e_{n-1}$ and

$e_n=a_n+b_n+c_n=3e_{n-1}-(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1})=3e_{n-1}-(e_{n-1}-c_{n-1})=2e_{n-1}+e_{n-2}$;

so $e_1=3, e_2=7, e_3=17, e_4=41, e_5=99$.

Since $a_n=b_n$ by symmetry, $e_n=2a_n+e_{n-1}\;\;$and therefore $a_n=\frac{1}{2}(e_n-e_{n-1})=\frac{1}{2}(e_{n-1}+e_{n-2})$.

Then $a_6=\frac{1}{2}(e_5+e_4)=70$, and

we must deduct the number of 6-digit codes ending in 4 which do not include a 9.

Since there are $2^5$ such codes, there are $70-2^5=70-32=38$ possibilities.

$-----------------------------------$

An alternate way to count the number of possibilities is to break this up into cases, based on the number $\;\;l$ of consecutive 4's at the end of the code.

Then $1\le l\le4$, and the digit preceding the string of 4's must be a 6; so

there are $\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^4 (e_m-2^m)=1+3+9+25=38$ possibilities. (where $m=5-l$)